# Friction force variable or non-variable force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

suppose I'm given the co-efficient of friction of a surface where the normal force of a block is equal to $mg$ and the block is at rest. Now will the friction force change over time if I displace the block from it's initial position to a distance $d$? or it will be kinetic friction co-efficient*mg throughout the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a two bodies undergo relative motion, they pull each other with kinetic friction, i.e
F = (kinetic friction coefficient)(normal force)
When two bodies have the ***tendency*** to undergo relative motion, they subject each other to static friction.

**To answer your question:** If you displace the block, then the block and ground experience relative motion, hence pulling each other with Kinetic friction.
Which means, that throughout the displacement(since there  would be relative motion during the complete displacement)  the frictional force applied between them would not change.

Answer (score 1):

In the ideal world, the coefficient of kinetic friction is constant.  In the real world, the coefficient of kinetic friction varies with the relative velocity of the surfaces.